# C++/CLR Passing multiple arguments in threads

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli

When one create a new thread, using `ThreadStart()` how does one pass multiple arguments to the function?

Here's an example:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;

public ref class Animal
{
public:
    void Hungry(Object^ food, int quantity);
};

void Animal::Hungry(Object^ food, int quantity)
{
    Console::WriteLine("The animal eats " + quantity.ToString() + food);
}

void main()
{
    Animal^ test = gcnew Animal;
    Thread^ threads = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(test, &Animal::Hungry)); 

    threads->Start("Grass", 1); //need to pass 2nd argument! 
}
```

It works fine with just one argument (if I remove int quantity and just have Object^ food) since ParameterizedThreadStart takes only an Object^

Comment: You pass the argument to the Thread::Start() method.  The function you call must take a single Object^ argument.  Cast it back to String^ with safe_cast.

Comment: @HansPassant Okay I was able to get it working like you said, but how do I pass multiple arguments? Also I had to change ThreadStart() to ParameterizedThreadStart()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in any other situation where you have to put multiple values into one object, you either:

- create a wrapper class or struct (the *clean* way)
- or use some predefined one like `Tuple` (the *lazy* way)

Here's the lazy way:

```
void Animal::Hungry(Object^ param)
{
    auto args = safe_cast<Tuple<String^, int>^>(param);
    Console::WriteLine("The animal eats {1} {0}", args->Item1, args->Item2);
}

void main()
{
    Animal^ test = gcnew Animal;
    Thread^ threads = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(test, &Animal::Hungry));
    threads->Start(Tuple::Create("Grass", 1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer worked well. I wish C++ CLR had better thread support, but I'm glad you came to the rescue.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with threading. The .NET framework has pretty good threading support (Threads, TPL, PLINQ, etc). The sad thing is that C++/CLI doesn't support managed lambdas.

Comment: I see. It was quite a pain to pass arguments in multithreading. Glad it became easier in C++11.